# How do search engines analyze dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I want to inject dynamically these tags using JavaScript.

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta name='title' content='Foo - All Your Bookmarks in One Place.'>
<meta name='description' content='A better way to bookmark.'>
```

So if you click: View->Source, they would not show up as they are created dynamically.

But they would be inserted into the DOM automatically when the page is requested using a function linked to window.onload.

Will search engines know about them?

Comment: Virtually any system that might actually use your meta tags will not run your script.

Comment: In short...Bots are dumb browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, although Google might be processing javascript. You should probably have read https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ before posting here.

Check a more up to date answer here : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/search-engine-misunderstanding#10006925

Comment: Of course they **can**, the question is if they have a reason for it.

Comment: And it's now [deprecated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.jp/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Answer (score 4):

1. No. Generally speaking search engines do not process or handle JavaScript. So if you're generating content via JavaScript is most likely will not be seen by the search engines. However they do have the capability to parse *some* JavaScript and Google does support a [crawlable Ajax standard](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) (which does not apply here) so this *may* be found by them but you should not count on it.
2. Meta tags no longer affect your rankings so from an SEO point of view this question really doesn't matter. The only affect these tags may have on the search engines is [they *may* use your meta description tag in the search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/15974/1253) but that is not guaranteed.

**update**

Search engines see the source code they download from your server, not the results of any operations that JavaScript or Flash, etc, produce. So even though it is in the DOM it only is there after the JavaScript is executed. If the crawler doesn't execute the JavaScript then it's never in the DOM as far as they are concerned.

**update #2**

Search engine crawlers are essentially the equivalent of a person with usability and accessibility needs. To see what a search engine crawler sees turn off your images, CSS, and JavaScript. Better yet, view your site through a screen reader like [Jaws](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp), or use a [text browser like Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: But the tags are automatiaclly written to the DOM..do the crawlers look at the DOM, or the same thing you see when you click view->source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google _does_ execute JavaScript: http://www.jefftk.com/news/2012-01-11.html

Comment: Google will execute some javascript but mostly it's basic stuff. advanced scripts are still effectively hidden to them.

Comment: Does google make a page request or statically traverse files on a server...they don't have access to just traverse servers...I would assume that they must make a page request....

Comment: They request pages just like any other user does.

Comment: So if my JS fires on a window.onload event...why wouldn't fire on the Google / Server side? If they make a page request I doubt they would disable javascript..

Comment: They can't do anything on your server, only you can. Plus firing javascript isn't as easy as it sounds. Bots by default cannot execute javascript. That's why webmasters are told to never depend on javascript to deliver content and to use progressive enhancement instead.

Comment: http://swapped.tumblr.com/post/23133779276/google-bot-now-crawls-arbitrary-javascript-sites

Answer (score 1):

I'd say almost definitely not, sorry.

Comment: What does the crawler traverse?  If it's in the DOM it's in the DOM right?

Comment: The crawler typically traverses the DOM before DOM modification, iirc.